# Custom SP Workflow within Visual Studio 2012 - Create Doc Set and then move document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio-2012

First of all my apologies if this has already been asked and answered elsewhere, i have been trawling.

I have the task of creating a workflow that is triggered on a specific list upon a items field (ReferenceNumber) being populated. If so, then a lookup runs to check whether a doc set (under same reference number) within another library already exists. If so then move the file into it. If not, then create the doc set and then move the file into it.

Copying a document into another library location is fine, and even creating the doc set within that library is fine, but i'm falling short when I try and move the file into the document set. It gives me the option for the list, but unfortunately there is no further specifics.

Can anyone lend a hand? Your time and efforts are truly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking into the 'Copy Item Extended' option that is available in previous versions of SP and SPD and unfortunately are having little luck in trying to replicate this feature with SPD2013, any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I found that the only real option is to use a 2010 workflow within SPD 2013 as thats the only way of accessing the 'Copy Item Extended' option which to my amazement is not present within 2013 workflows at all. Further details can be found under the following link.

[social.msdn.microsoft article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c19ca2ea-6760-466d-9433-9d5a0d0883e4/move-files-from-one-document-set-to-another-document-set-using-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization)